# RockMongo shows <Mongo Binary Data> instead of content

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to force MongoDB to show the binary data instead of displaying `<Mongo Binary Data>`? I know it is not always possible, but best effort would be enough.

I have seen this in both RockMongo and MongoDB shell.

Additional information: I am saving strings in various encodings (not just UTF-8), but I would still like to be able to read them in shell or RockMongo (at least ASCII characters, others could be replaced with `\xx` or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it in RockMongo for myself. In app/classes/VarExportor.php find function `_formatVar($var)` there is a `switch` that handles different types of data. Just add:

```
case "MongoBinData":
    $this->_jsonParams[$this->_paramIndex] = 
        'MongoBinData("' . $var->bin . '")';
    return $this->_param($this->_paramIndex);
```

Maybe one should also escape the `$var->bin` - not sure, but other vars are not escaped either so I'm guessing some other layer takes care of that.

Hope it helps someone.